# Unable to add VF page to Custom Object Layout on Production

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, permissions, page-layout

I have a VF page with that uses a custom controller that I'm trying to add to a custom object layout. in my sandbox, I can see the VF page in the VF pages options for the edit layout page. On production however, I don't see the option.

I've read before that you have to use the standard controller, but why would it be working in the sandbox and not production? Is there some permission setting or something that I'm missing?

controller for VF page on production:

```
apex:page controller="xExtDataExtension" id="thePage" sidebar="false"
```

controller for VF page in sandbox:

```
apex:page controller="xExtDataExtension" id="thePage" sidebar="false"
```

I literally just deployed from sandbox to production along with the controller. It works in the sandbox though.

Comment: It absolutely should not be possible to add without `standardController`. Are you sure you have the same opening `<apex:page>` tag?

Comment: Are the permissions for the VF page and the controller the same in production and in the sandbox.  I've had similar problems when they didn't match.

Comment: i'm logged in as system admin, checked in users->profiles and it says i have access. is there another place i should be looking for permission issues?

Comment: What happens if you actually add the VF page to the layout in Sandbox, save the layout and view a record with it? I doubt it will work. On the off chance it does, try also deploying that layout to production and see what happens there.

Comment: it works great in the sandbox when saved and viewed with a record in it. it passes the id along and all the data points i'm generating and passing to it work perfectly. not sure if i can deploy that layout to production, need to check with someone else who's not in the office yet.... i will if i can though.

Comment: sorry searching but can't find, how do you deploy the page layout for a custom object?

Comment: @dkhendo Change Set is easiest; honestly not sure if you'd need to deploy the whole object with the MDAPI.

Comment: yeah i looked through the change sets and wasn't able to find just the layout. this is such an odd problem all together...