# Unable to add VF page to Account layout after being pushed from sandbox?

Tags: visualforce, deployment, permissions, page-layout

I found [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70126/unable-to-add-vf-page-to-custom-object-layout-on-production) question on SF.SE, and I am experiencing the same issue. After pushing a custom Visualforce page from Sandbox to Production, I cannot add it to my Account page layout. Does anyone know how this can be resolved? All of the permissions I have in both production and sandbox are identical.

It may also be worthwhile to note that I am not binding the standard controller. I am only using a custom controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to include the VF page inline with the account page you will need to use the `standardController="Account"` in the `apex:page` component.

You could also create a second page that does this and include the page you have deployed in that VF page using `<apex:include>`

Ultimately the page needs to be using the standard controller

Comment: Why is this allowed in Sandbox, but not in Production, though? That doesn't seem to make much sense. Is this a bug, or intended functionality? In the process of pushing changes, so we will know soon enough.

Comment: If you are trying to put it inline with standard detail page it should not. Maybe you are mistaken or removed the standard controller?

Comment: No, it's definitely absent the standard controller, but can be added to the page just fine. My issue now is that, after updating the VF page to use the standard controller, and modifying the class to accept the standard controller, I'm receiving an error when running my test indicating that the "Constructor is not defined."

Comment: @toolshed you will need to update your tests as well. To the best of my knowledge it cannot be added without the standardcontroller.

Comment: it appears that you are correct. Thank you very much for the assistance, sir. I appreciate it.

Comment: Still curious how you were able to add the page without the standard controller

Comment: That makes two of us, @Eric. I figure that it must be a low priority bug. The changes were deployed via a change set. Once I refactored the code to use the standard controller, everything worked as intended. Certainly strange.